# Command to generate all aplications from Startup in a txt file

Tags: startup

I need a command to generate the list of all applications and programs which start when I turn on my laptop and login in Ubuntu 12.04.

I  want to make a .txt file with them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with just a single command since programs tend to be in several locations (based on when they need to start and if they need to start for a system or for a single user). 2 main directories that hold services that start during boot time ...

```
/etc/init/
/etc/init.d/
```

But these directories include more than just the programs that get started: some might be turned off because of a configuration. Some are old scripts and are there for backward compatibility and do nothing since they got turned to an upstart service.

Then there are also ...

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
~/.config/autostart
```

These last 2 have .desktop files so the command they use is inside the file itself.

If you want them all into a text file you could do this, as a 1 liner, from command line:

```
ls -lR /etc/init/ >  /tmp/test.txt && 
ls -lR /etc/init.d/ >> /tmp/test.txt && 
ls -lR /etc/xdg/autostart >> /tmp/test.txt && 
ls -lR ~/.config/autostart >> /tmp/test.txt
```

This would get you a recursively long list of all the contents in a file called test.txt inside /tmp/. It will be a long list but I also do not claim it to be perfect: it is totally possible that there are more programs started inside a `.bashrc` for instance.